# kill -SIGCONT does not work

Tags: linux, bash, signals

I want to use SIGTSTP(or SIGSTOP) to pause a process and resume it later with SIGCONT. SIGTSTP and SIGSTOP work just as expected, but SIGCONT does not woke up the stopped process some times.

For example:
SIGCONT works well with the find command:

`find /
kill -SIGSTOP $pid_of_the_find_proc
[1]+ Stopped find /
kill -SIGCONT $pid_of_the_find_proc
// find / woke up`

But when I tested it with the sleep command, it just failed.

`sleep 100
kill -SIGSTOP $pid_of_the_sleep_proc
[1]+ Stopped sleep 100
kill -SIGCONT $pid_of_the_sleep_proc
// nothing happened after sending the SIGCONT signal`

However, bash's builtin command `fg` worked with sleep well

`sleep 100
kill -SIGSTOP $pid_of_the_sleep_proc
[1]+ Stopped sleep 100
kill -SIGCONT $pid_of_the_sleep_proc
fg 1
// the sleep process woke up after the fg command`

So my question is why `kill -SIGCONT` does not work with sleep and why does `fg` work. By the way, I run these tests on my Ubuntu 13.10 x86-64 pc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @William Pursell, you are right. The sleep process did woke up in the background. I just did not notice it.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `sleep` resumes execution? It'll continue to sleep until its timer expires...

Answer (score 2):

How do you know that sending SIGCONT doesn't wake up the sleep process? What do you expect to happen?
The fg command wakes up the process and brings it to the foreground (hence fg).
The bg command wakes up the process and brings it to the background (hence bg).

In implementation details, the shell uses wait on a process in the foreground, while it doesn't use wait on processes in the background.

So after SIGCONT your sleep probably continues to run in the background. You could wait for 100 seconds after sending SIGCONT, then the sleep command should have terminated and you should get a notification (immediately or after pressing return, depending on the configuration of your shell).

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for the explanation.  Now, I wonder how to bring it to the foreground...

Comment: @PyTis you... call `fg` on it.